# Can't display ONLY my GeoServer layer using OpenLayers 6

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers

I am having some trouble getting my OpenLayers 6 maps to display my own layer from GeoServer. The code below let me choose between **OSM** , **Bing Map** or **CartoDb** as a base layer and displays a default GeoServer layer, **topp:states**! 
And all this works fine.

But in the end, as I attempted to display my own GeoServer layer "**grupo**" created from PostGIS DB, nothing appears. The `GetMap` request is working fine as shown here:

[image: Here(Network inspect)]

so it must be something wrong within the layer or projection (my guess)...

This layer "**grupo**" was created with [EPSG:3763](http://www.epsg-registry.org/?display=entity&urn=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3763). There are no errors in the developer console logs, if I open the GeoServer log there is record of my own GeoServer layer "**grupo**" and **topp:states** being requested!

My GeoServer layer "Setup"

Layer Data

[image: GeoServer - Layer Data]

Tile Caching

[image: GeoServer - Tile Caching]

LayerPreview

[image: GeoServer - LayerPreview]

LayerPreview url -> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sig/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sig%3Agrupo&bbox=-933103.256159661%2C5052848.3016269%2C-931781.706532744%2C5053702.88175803&width=768&height=496&srs=EPSG%3A3763&format=application/openlayers

Here's the code:

```
function init(){

    const map = new ol.Map({
            view : new ol.View({

               center: ol.proj.transform([-8.3770108, 41.2771817],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
                    //center: [-932510.7343462185,5053142.307944268],
                zoom: 15,
                maxZoom: 20,
                minZoom: 4

            }),
            target : 'js-map'
    })


    // Base Maps
const openStreetMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source : new ol.source.OSM(),
    visible: true,
    title: 'OpenStreetMap'
})

const bingMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: 'AmsC0864kukoBixOpup8lsv3yFO_qzXenrScHMmdHz5HVDSI0wZsGcP9DyW9zIU-',
            imagerySet: 'Aerial'
    }),
    visible: false,
    title:'BingMap'
})

const CartoDB = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
        "url" : "http://{a-c}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    }),
    visible: false,
    title:'CartoDB'
})


//layer group
const baseLayerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers: [
        openStreetMap, bingMap, CartoDB
    ]
})


//Layer Switcher (BaseLayers)
const baseLayerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.baseSideBar > input[type=radio]');
for(let baseLayerElement of baseLayerElements){
    baseLayerElement.addEventListener('change', function(){
        let baseLayerElementValue = this.value;
        baseLayerGroup.getLayers().forEach(function(element, index, array){
        let baseLayerTitle = element.get('title');
        element.setVisible(baseLayerTitle === baseLayerElementValue);
        })
    })
}
map.addLayer(baseLayerGroup);


 // layers geoserver
 var wms_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states','VERSION':'1.1.1', 'TILED': true},
    serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
   });
     map.addLayer(wms_layer);

 var wms_layer1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sig/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'sig:grupo','VERSION':'1.1.1', 'TILED': true},
    serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
   });
      map.addLayer(wms_layer1);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please use the Picture button whenever you wish to embed images.

Comment: And what is the question? What does not work? Any errors in the debugger console/network?

Comment: No erros in console/network .. and GeoServer does receive a getmap request . Still, the layer doesnt show in the map... The question is what is wrong , there is no errors, there is no display ...

Comment: But don't keep us in suspense what "funny" thing happened? Try turning the log level up and then add the relevant request and log messages to the question

Comment: The "funny" thing is that my geoserver Layer doesnt work on 1.3.0 version. But I dont think thats it . Sorry I dont know what u mean with turning the log level up , as I am new at this . But I can try to put some images from the network,etc. ( Edited above)

Comment: Please reopen, I dont know how I can explain better

Comment: Its in the queue for reopen votes. Wait a little until enough members have cast their votes.

Comment: I post a new one more detailed and clear https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346103/cant-display-my-geoserver-layer-using-openlayers6

Comment: @Darish You can [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/346059/edit) your own post

Comment: Can the moderators leave some post open , so someone can help me? I been pretty active trying to explain my problem(I didn't have much chance since it was soon closed). You are more active trying to figure out a problems with the posts edits than with my question.   As stated - "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one."  I edited this first a couple of times, before I try to open a new one . Guess another day waiting to have a post up , instead of waiting for a hint where the problem might be ..

Comment: This is getting a bit confusing. Question is now completely changed from the original one.

Comment: Please ... I cannot create a new one as it got instantly close , so I edited this one to my current situation, Its still somehow the same . I just kept working on it and updated . Now I can display geoserver Layers . Only my Layer is not working ... ..but can we leave this behind and focus on the current question, any hint where the problem can be ?

Comment: `The GetMap request is working fine as shown Here`, it is not clear to me from that statement, do you mean that when you run the generated request in a browser that an image is returned?

Comment: Yes , getmap request is also showing up in GeoServer Log . So it should be returning an image

Comment: In the first version of your question you included also display of returned .png image from debugger, which was empty and transparent. How does images look now in debugger?

Comment: Still transparent, but its the same with topp:states default layer , also return transparent, only when I go to the zone of the layer does it start to return images with stuff in debugger. So I am assuming my layer is the same. It can be on the map, just on the wrong location  or really small ?

Comment: Openlayers transform projections automatically , so even if my layer is in EPSG:3763 it would transform automatically to EPSG:3857, right?

Comment: `Yes , getmap request is also showing up in GeoServer Log . So it should be returning an image`  That's not correct.  The request showing in the log, and the request showing in the browser debugger, don't mean that an image should be returned, just that a GetMap request is being made.  That's why I asked if the request shows an image in a browser (away from the application).

Comment: `Openlayers transform projections automatically` no openlayers doesn't do that.  But GeoServer may just respond to an EPSG:3857 request for the layer if the WMS hasn't been configured to offer only a selected number of  CRS.  Does the GetCapabilities response for your service show that EPSG:3857 is supported?

Comment: So I try to see the wms GetCapabilities by doing this :  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities    , and yes, 3857 is in the supported EPSG projections

Comment: same with the GetCapabilities of my layer http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sig/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities  . Its also supported

Comment: solved ! Thanks anyway guys !  you can close ?  xD It turns out it was the layer fault way, not geoserver/openlayer related !

Comment: What was the fault?

Comment: If you found the solution, it would be appropriate to publish is as an answer, with detailed description of the problem, cause of the problem and the solution. This could then help somebody else with similar problem. For this to be possible one more person has to vote for reopening the question.

Comment: I was inserting into my sql table epsg:3857 coords , but I was declaring them as epsg:3763 . -  example :``` (13 , 'Pr. Dr. Luis', 3, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-932105.23114493198227137 5053533.93223438877612352, -932102.83540574880316854 5053478.83023317437618971)', 3763)), ``` So my layer was showing up fine in geoserver , but really it wasnt ...